# How to remove unnecessary values being fetched by WITH ROLLUP and add TOTAL instead?

Tags: mysql

well my query finally seems to be fetching the total count with WITH ROLLUP clause but then some unnecessary values are geting fetched on the same line whereas i want it to show only TOTAL 2581.75 but i cannot figure it out.

could someone show me the right way to do it? I am posting a screenshot of the values which needs to disappear with red

[image: Here is a screenshot]

and here is my query

```
SELECT reference, product_name, product_description, product_bin, product_bin_location, product_quantity, product_reorder, product_price, SUM(product_price * product_quantity) AS total_value, date 
FROM product 
GROUP BY reference WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Replace single columns with `CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN {column} END AS {column}`. [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7da14296ace235a3c4c7e65fb93efd75)

Comment: @Akina can you please show me how? i am not getting it how to do it rightly. much appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at the example? What is unclear in it?

Comment: as is how to impliment your query im not very pro that is why its kind of confsing how must i query your example with my code

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT reference, 
       CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN product_name END product_name, 
       CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN product_description END product_description, 
       CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN product_bin END product_bin, 
       CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN product_bin_location END product_bin_location, 
       CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN product_quantity END product_quantity, 
       CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN product_reorder END product_reorder, 
       CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN product_price ELSE 'TOTAL' END product_price, 
       SUM(product_price * product_quantity) AS total_value, 
       CASE WHEN reference IS NOT NULL THEN date END date
FROM product 
GROUP BY reference WITH ROLLUP
```